# Inserting into database just before leaving the page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

This is how I capture user leaving a page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    var message = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
}

</script>
```

Now what I want is to capture user clicking "leave this page" and insert something into database.How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (try to) capture the user leaving if you don't show them the dialog. (If you do show them the dialog, there aren't a lot of options.)

You will have to do a synchronous request to the server in `onebeforeunload`.

```
onbeforeunload = function() {
    var data = 'id=123';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('POST', '/imleavingthepage', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

But know that this is not necessarily reliable. `onbeforeunload` is not standard, and the browser may not even send the request.

I have done this in Chrome, however, and it is usually successful.

Comment: Ok, I will not show the dialog but pls Help me in calling a method or a click event on closing of tab/browser so that I can insert my data in database

Comment: @MangalPandey, I have provided that, though this will *never* be completely reliable. If a user tells a browser to shut down it make not want to want for your page to make a request to your server.

Comment: FYI, this is why Google Docs sometimes thinks you are still on a document even after you have closed that tab. Even Google is susceptible to this limitation.